# Java application in Windows' volume mixer

Tags: java

This is how my application looks in volume mixer:

[image: java application in volume mixer]

Is there any way to change appearance of Java application in volume mixer? Even custom icon would be nice. In the Task Manager there's also "Java(TM)..." but the icon isn't default.

Comment: If it is offering a volume control for Java (in general), rather than your app. (I'm not sure whether it is or not, but *suspect* that is the case), then there will be no option to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with [jar2exe](http://www.jar2exe.com/)!

[image]
[image]

But there's free 30-days trial *only* for test purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to take a look at [this software](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: No luck for me in Task Manager as well as Mixer, "Custom process name" checked but stays "Java (TM)...". Gonna check another wrapper.

Comment: Although there's no change in Volume Mixer.